# How to configure Maven from Eclipse to automatically download jar files?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am new to Maven and Eclipse.  I am using Eclipse that came bundled with Spring Tool Suite.  I am using the following:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_45
Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE
```

I am trying to get Maven to resolve dependencies from within Eclipse. I have Maven installed on my desktop.  I have the M2 and M2_HOME set.

This is what I have done in Eclipse

1. Create a Dynamic Web Project
2. Convert the project to a Maven Project (Configure > Convert to Maven Project)
3. Add dependencies to pom.xml using the Eclipse editor

When the jars for the dependencies are in my local repository, the jars get automatically included under Maven Dependencies.  When they are not in my local repository, the jars do not automatically get included.  I have to select the dependency and click 'Manage' to get the jars downloaded and included.  How can I configure Maven/Eclipse so that ALL added dependencies get automatically downloaded?

Comment: If you go to Project menu in STS, is the "Build Automatically" option checked?

Comment: Yes, that option is checked.

Comment: If you go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven, is the "Offline" option unchecked?

Comment: No, offline is NOT checked.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the project, Maven->Update Project...

Comment: Yes, I had updated the project.